# Jsfiddle demo to html page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this jsfiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/yd6xmtvq/, and want to implement this on a html page. I included the css files of the bootstrap in the html, and they are located in the same directory as tht html file. This is how my code is setup:

```
  <html>

<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link href="bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap-slider.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var minSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-min");
var maxSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-max");

$('#ex1').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'RAM: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#ex2').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Disk Space: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#ex3').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'CPU : ' + value + ' Cores';
    }
});

// If You want to change input text using slider handler
$('.slider').on('slide', function(slider){

  var val1 = $("#ex1").val();
  var val2 = $("#ex2").val();
  var val3 = $("#ex3").val();
  $("#inputValue").val(parseInt(val1)+ parseInt(val2)+ parseInt(val3));

});

// If you want to change slider using input text
$("#inputValue").on("keyup", function() {
    var val = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value, 10) || minSliderValue);
    this.value = val > maxSliderValue ? maxSliderValue : val;
    $('#ex1','ex2','ex3').slider('setValue', val);
});


</script>


</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="slider" id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" />
      <hr />

  <input class="slider" id="ex2" data-slider-id='ex1Slider2' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" />
       <hr />
      <input  class="slider" id="ex3" data-slider-id='ex1Slider3' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" />

       <hr />

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" value="0" readonly />


      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just copy all to a file and name it `myfile.html`...

Comment: `document.ready` for the 1e7th time on SO

Comment: Scripts in jsfiddle are by default executed at the `onload` event. You run your script before any of the element in the `body` are in the DOM so jQuery cannot find any of them at the time the script runs.

Comment: Check my answer below, you have to correct three things and the last one is very minor but required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct the following three things.

1. You haved added `jQuery` after `bootstrap-slider.js`. `JQuery` should be
   added before the `bootstrap-slider.js` library.
2. You have the scripts inside the `<head>` tag which should be down to
   all the html elements, otherwise should be enclosed with `$(document).ready`.
3. Also you have missed a minor css style to include `.wrapper { }`

Working copy:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <style>
    .wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

  </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>




</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="slider" id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" />
      <hr />

  <input class="slider" id="ex2" data-slider-id='ex1Slider2' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" />
       <hr />
      <input  class="slider" id="ex3" data-slider-id='ex1Slider3' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" />

       <hr />

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" value="0" readonly />


      </div>
  
  <script>

var minSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-min");
var maxSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-max");

$('#ex1').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'RAM: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#ex2').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Disk Space: ' + value + 'GB';
    }
});

$('#ex3').slider({
    value : 0,
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'CPU : ' + value + ' Cores';
    }
});

// If You want to change input text using slider handler
$('.slider').on('slide', function(slider){

  var val1 = $("#ex1").val();
  var val2 = $("#ex2").val();
  var val3 = $("#ex3").val();
  $("#inputValue").val(parseInt(val1)+ parseInt(val2)+ parseInt(val3));

});

// If you want to change slider using input text
$("#inputValue").on("keyup", function() {
    var val = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value, 10) || minSliderValue);
    this.value = val > maxSliderValue ? maxSliderValue : val;
    $('#ex1','ex2','ex3').slider('setValue', val);
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```